# How to run appium automation test cases on multiple android devices

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, appium

I want to test my android app on multiple devices connected to my local network. I am using appium test framework and written test cases using Junit. Which steps I need to perform.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run multiple Appium servers on different ports:

```
 node ~/appium/bin/appium.js -a 127.0.0.1 --session-override --port 4733
 node ~/appium/bin/appium.js -a 127.0.0.1 --session-override --port 4743
```

and pass specific URL while creating Appium driver instances:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4733/wd/hub
http://127.0.0.1:4743/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run multiple Appium serves on different ports and attach device to it

```
$ appium -p 4723 -U deviceName1
$ appium -p 4725 -U deviceName2
```

Here is an article which discusses how to Automate UI testing in multiple devices. Also provides implementation details.[How I automated testing for an app spanning interactions between multiple devices](https://medium.com/@charianand.maurya/how-i-automated-testing-for-an-app-spanning-interactions-between-multiple-devices-5cf3ca9df8d0)